# (NoMethodError) Undefined private method in model - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, private-methods

I'm building a simple ecommerce webpage and the functionality I want to create is:

User clicks an "ADD TO CART" button in one of the products --> the ORDER is created with the user_id --> the ORDER_ITEM is created with order_id and product_id.

I want to build all the logic in OrderItem model:

```
class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product

  before_validation :generate_order

  private

  def self.generate_order(user)
    if Order.find_by(status: 1)
      order = Order.find_by(status: 1)
    else
      order = Order.new(status: 1, total: 0, subtotal: 0, date: Date.today())
      order.user = user 
      order.save!
    end
    return order
  end
end
```

Basically, if there is an Order open (status = 1) then return that order and if not create one.

And in the OrderItem controller:

```
class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
        @order = OrderItem.generate_order(current_user)
        @order_item = OrderItem.new
        @order_item.product = @product
        @order_item.order = @order
        if @order_item.save!
            redirect_to cart_path
        else
            redirect_to root_path
        end
    end

    def delete
    end
end
```

Everything goes well until it arrives to the .save! point where it throws this error:

```
undefined method `generate_order' for #<OrderItem:0x00007fe8f77552c8>
```

I checked the logs and everything seems to have been created well:

```
>> @order_item
=> #<OrderItem id: nil, order_id: 1, product_id: 65, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> @order
=> #<Order id: 1, subtotal: 0, total: 0, date: "2021-09-05 00:00:00", user_id: 5, created_at: "2021-09-05 00:00:12", updated_at: "2021-09-05 00:00:12", status: 1>
>> @product
=> #<Product id: 65, name: "Shou Mei", description: "Sequi dolores facilis rerum quo odit veritatis ips...", price: 5893, rating: 5, user_id: 13, created_at: "2021-09-03 23:54:46", updated_at: "2021-09-03 23:54:47", availability: 2>
```

Why is throwing that error and how could I make it right? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line in your model is the problem:

```
before_validation :generate_order
```

You only have a class method `self.generate_order`, but this would be looking for a instance method. Judging from the code inside `self.generate_order` it doesn't seem you want that to be checked before each validation, so you can delete the line (or write an instance method that serves whatever purpose you had in mind).